# What is the working of mathematics in python vscoder

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, trigonometry

Here is my code:

```
print('Welcome to program that finds what kind of triangle is formed by given points')
print('Please enter the required points.')
x1=float(input('x1: '))
y1=float(input('y1: '))
x2=float(input('x2: '))
y2=float(input('y2: '))
x3=float(input('x3: '))
y3=float(input('y3: '))
area= x1*(y2-y3)+x2*(y3-y1)+x3*(y1-y2)
def distance(a,b,c,d):
    return ((c-a)**2+(d-b)**2)**0.5
d1= distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
d2= distance(x2,y2,x3,y3)
d3= distance(x3,y3,x1,y1)
if area == 0:
    print('The given points are collinear')
else:
    if d1==d2==d3:
        print('The given points form an equilateral triangle')
    elif d1==d2 or d2 ==d3 or d3==d1:
        print('The given points form an isosceles triangle')
    else:
        print('The given points form a scalene triangle')
if d1**2+d2**2==d3**2 or d2**2+d3**2==d1**2 or d1**2+d3**2==d2**2:
    print('The given points form a right angled triangle')
import math
slope1= math.fabs(area/d1/d2)
slope2= math.fabs(area/d2/d3)
slope3= math.fabs(area/d1/d3)
inrad1=math.asin(slope1)
inrad2=math.asin(slope2)
inrad3=math.asin(slope3)
indeg1= math.degrees(inrad1)
indeg2= math.degrees(inrad2)
indeg3= math.degrees(inrad3)
print('The angles of given triangle in degrees are: ')
print(indeg1)
print(indeg2)
print(indeg3)
print('The sum of all angles in a triangle is '+str(indeg1+indeg2+indeg3))
```

When I enter some known coordinates like an equilateral triangle, or any know right angled triangle, the results are correct.

But when I enter random numbers, with decimals `(32.432,-21.432 etc)`, irrespective of the points I take, the sum of all angles in a triangle should be 180. But when I take random numbers, the sum of angles is way too off (sometimes it even shows less than 100 degrees for sum of angles)

Is this a problem of my code, or is this something related to approximations done by vscoder?

Comment: Could you at least give specific input example with the output your code gives and the one you actually expect? Please have a look at [ask] and how to provide a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the use of "math.asin(slope1)" in the code needs to be modified, instead of calculating the radian value based on the side length, please use the following code:

> ```
> print('Welcome to program that finds what kind of triangle is formed by given points')
> print('Please enter the required points.')
> x1=float(input('x1: '))
> y1=float(input('y1: '))
> x2=float(input('x2: '))
> y2=float(input('y2: '))
> x3=float(input('x3: '))
> y3=float(input('y3: '))
> area= x1*(y2-y3)+x2*(y3-y1)+x3*(y1-y2)
> def distance(a,b,c,d):
>     return ((c-a)**2+(d-b)**2)**0.5
>     
> d1= distance(x1,y1,x2,y2)
>
>
> d2= distance(x2,y2,x3,y3)
> d3= distance(x3,y3,x1,y1)
> if area == 0:
>     print('The given points are collinear')
> else:
>     if d1==d2==d3:
>         print('The given points form an equilateral triangle')
>     if d1==d2 or d2 ==d3 or d3==d1:
>         print('The given points form an isosceles triangle')
>     else:
>         print('The given points form a scalene triangle')
>         
>         if d1**2+d2**2==d3**2 or d2**2+d3**2==d1**2 or d1**2+d3**2==d2**2:
>             print('The given points form a right angled triangle')
>
> import math
> # slope1= math.fabs(area/d1/d2)
> # slope2= math.fabs(area/d2/d3)
> # slope3= math.fabs(area/d1/d3)
> # inrad1=math.asin(slope1)
> # inrad2=math.asin(slope2)
> # inrad3=math.asin(slope3)
> # indeg1= math.degrees(inrad1)
> # indeg2= math.degrees(inrad2)
> # indeg3= math.degrees(inrad3)
>
> indeg1 = math.degrees(math.acos((d1**2 + d2**2 - d3**2) / (2 * d1 * d2)))
> indeg2 = math.degrees(math.acos((d2**2 + d3**2 - d1**2) / (2 * d2 * d3)))
> indeg3 = math.degrees(math.acos((d3**2 + d1**2 - d2**2) / (2 * d3 * d1)))
>
>
> print('The angles of given triangle in degrees are: ')
> print(indeg1)
> print(indeg2)
> print(indeg3)
> print('The sum of all angles in a triangle is '+ str(indeg1+indeg2+indeg3))
> ```

Run:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you I realised my mistake. Using asin gives values only between 0 to 90 degrees. So the code I used dosn't work for obtuse angled triangles. acos gives values between 0 and 180 . Thank you so much!!!!